# Cannot download base64 image from a browser from an aws lambda function?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, aws-lambda, base64

I create a node js lambda function to crop and return an image from any image url.

The function creates a GET API which returns a cropped image.The API is working fine, I am able to download any image from postman but even there I am not getting the image preview, I have to manually download. Although the downloaded base64 image is correct and working in the browser if put directly.

I need a way for it to work directly in the html `<img>` tag.
The api is something like - `https://aws-lambda-fn-image-resizer/{encoded image url}`

Comment: Are you returning a correct `content-type` header?

Comment: Currently its set to ``image.png``

Comment: try setting it to `image/png`? Not sure if this is the problem or not.

Comment: its already set.